# selenium chromedriver timeout exception ImplicitlyWait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After the last Chrome browser updating 64.0.3282.186 I'm getting an exception in the following line

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

The exception is: "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:59250/session/926e6ba1b399f2ce4efbaeef7e01dace/timeouts timed out after 60 seconds."}   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException"

- ChromeDriver 2.35
- Selenium.WebDriver 2.35.1 (I can't update it to 3.x by some reasons)
- C# and framework 4.5.2

Does anyone faced with this issue or how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in the next Chrome browser version (more than a week later)